# Google Sign-In API failed : Network-Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-oauth, devops

I am facing issue in google sign-in api i.e'/api/v1/rest-auth/google'.
go through the code :
[image]
using react-google-login component. Everything works fine on our staging environment but on my local it throws error as show in screenshot.
Please help if anyone has any idea about it.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Backend server was not setup on my local machine.
After setting up the backend this was resolved.